Closed set of periodic points implies boundedness of primitive periods
I am trying to prove the following assertion, but I don't know how to proceed.

If $(X, f)$ is a discrete dynamical system (i. e. $f: X \rightarrow X$ is a continous map on the compact metric space $X$) and the set $\mathrm{Per} f$ of all periodic points is closed, then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there are no periodic points of primitive period greater than $N$.

My approach was the following: assume, for a contradiction, that the assertion is not true. Hence, we can find a sequence of points $(x_k)^\infty_{k=0}$ such that $x_k$ has primitive period $n_k$ for all $k$ and $n_k \rightarrow \infty.$ We can assume that $x_k \rightarrow x$ for some point $x \in X$ (passing to a subsequence if necessary).
To conclude it suffices to show that the point $x$ is not periodic. How can we prove that?

@PaulSinclair Aren't there example where $\text{Per}(f)$ is not closed and you can approximate periodic points with a sequence periodic points of arbitrarily large primitive period? I'm thinking of the left-shift map on two symbols. You need to contradict the fact that it is closed if this statement is true.

@User203940 - You are right. I was short on time and didn't put enough thought into it.

Let $C_n$ be a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $1/n$ centered at the origin. Consider $X := \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n \cup \{(0,0)\}$ equipped with the subspace topology (where the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the Euclidean one). You can check that $X$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. Define $f : X \rightarrow X$ as follows:

if $x \in C_n$ for some $n$, then $f(x)$ is a rotation on $C_n$ by angle $2\pi/n$.
if $x = (0,0)$, then $f(x) = x$.

Check that this defines a continuous function on $X$. Now, every point on $C_n$ is periodic with primitive period $n$ and the origin is fixed, so $X = \text{Per}(f)$; in particular, this is closed. On the other hand, there is no upper bound on the primitive periods.
